Prove uniqueness of Radon transform without using Fourier transform
The uniqueness of Radon transform can be expressed by the following claim (I assumed that the function has compact support for simplicity):

If a continuous function with compact support has zero integral over any hyperplane, then the function itself must be identically zero.

The standard proof I've seen uses the uniqueness of the Fourier transform. Specifically, since the complex exponential function $ e^{-2\pi i k \cdot x} $ is constant on each hyperplane $ x \cdot k = p $, this implies that the Fourier transform of the function must be zero, and hence the function itself is zero.
However, I find this proof to be somewhat indirect and not very intuitive. I’m wondering if there is a more direct proof of this result that does not rely on Fourier transform. Perhaps something more geometric or analytical that directly shows why the function must be zero based on the integrals over the hyperplanes being zero.
Any insights or alternative proofs would be greatly appreciated!

Another example: "if $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ has zero integral over every translate of a given bounded open set $\Omega\neq\emptyset$, then the function itself must be zero". If $\Omega$ is a cube or a parallelepiped, then it's elementary; if it is a ball, as far as I know, no way without Fourier transform
